# Is it possible for a bulb to behave like an inductor?

Tags: inductor, components

I have learned that the bulb has made from a **coil of tungsten**, not only bulbs many other components like electromagnet and electric motors also have coils in it. Is there a multiple behavior for this components i.e. does these components behave like an inductor at the same time? Does these components have inductance?

Comment: The tungsten coil is twisted such a way that it doesn't behave as an inductor. Motors mat be used as inductors, but better as speakers.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum   How it can be twisted in a suh a way that it doesn't behave as an inductor?

Comment: It's a double coil, so current flows in both directions and cancels the magnetic field.

Comment: Any conductor with electrons flowing through it behaves like an inductor as flowing electrons generate a magnetic field

Comment: The big bulbs may have 5" of wires to/from the base to the coil. That 10" will be approx. 250 nanoHenries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only ideal (theoretical) components have a single behavior. Real components always have multiple behavior. The secondary behavior is usually far less significant. In the case of an incandescent bulb, it is primarily a resistor, but a coil of tungsten will have some value of inductance as well. At AC power frequency, 50 or 60 Hz, the inductance will be insignificant, but if you use a bulb for a load in a radio frequency circuit, the inductance might be significant.

Answer (score 2):

The twists in the filament of a lamp are so small that nothing measurable happens due the extra inductance of the twists at 50 or 60Hz. You would need much more, say at least 10MHz to see significant difference. The twists are there to make a long enough wire possible in the available space.<sup>1</sup>

Despite it, the filament has an inductance, probably only tens of nanohenries, but it exists like in any wire.

<sup>1</sup> Just thought of something else. If the filament happens to have a mechanical resonant frequency near the AC line frequency, it can start to vibrate and break itself due the fatigue in the metal. Twists in the filament surely can significantly make the resonance frequency lower. If you slightly knock a lamp, you can see how its filament swings only few times in a second.

Comment: There is indeed inductance at high frequency.  Early in the vacuum tube era, using a lightbulb as a `dummy load` to test amateur radio transmitters was common.  But then, tube type rigs tolerate mismatched loads relatively well.  Today this would be a horrible idea, and is heavily warned against, not only because of the inductance, but because the *resistance* changes with temperature at different power levels.

Answer (score 2):

You can estimate the inductance of the filament coil from the dimensions using the formula for a single-layer air-core solenoid. [Here](http://electronbunker.ca/eb/InductanceCalc.html) is a calculator that does quite a thorough job.

For example, a coil with 20 turns of radius 1.5 mm and 15mm long will have an inductance of about 0.5uH. There will also be a bit of inductance in the wires leading to the coil because they are spread apart.

To put this in perspective, a 60W 120VAC bulb has a resistance (hot) of about 240 \$\Omega\$. The impedance of even 1uH at 60Hz is less than 0.5m\$\Omega\$, so the phase angle of the resulting current is essentially zero.

You don't want too much inductance from a thin bulb filament because that causes a magnetic field that can yank the filament around and shorten its life, or cause it to vibrate when operated from AC (which can cause an annoying audible noise). The surge when powered on from cold can be 10x the normal operating current. For low wattage high voltage bulbs the filament tends to be in a WW type of pattern with supports at several places rather than a coil. Home incandescent bulbs (back before they were banned) would often make an annoying noise when operated from a phase-control dimmer at low brightness level (thus seeing double mains frequency spikes of relatively high current).

Answer (score 0):

Wire inductance is always the ratio of diameter to length per unit length , typically ranging from 5 to  10 nH/cm for short lengths. For coils it’s enhanced by the compressed length to larger diameter ratio for same length of a linear filament.

The only significant factor is the added wire length, while wire pairs feeding it cancel there own inductance and better if twisted for mutual coupling. This is how “non-inductive” WW power resistors are made.

In reality they don’t add much compared to the long wires loosely coupled.

On line voltage due to the 1:10 thermal resistance you get much more spark power on switch contact than on switch open unlike real inductors.